# What are the different type of meditation mentioned in scriptures?

Tags: scripture, meditation, om, pranava-yoga

What are the different type of meditation mentioned in scriptures?
Like one is [Pranava yoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pranava_yoga) which is chanting [OM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om) sound.